# how to disable the warning (seems not one common warning )for this code sample in c++/gcc compile?

Tags: c++, warnings, pragma

[image]

how to disable the warning for this code sample in c++/gcc compile?
the warning seems it isn't a common warning. So how to disable it?

is it similar with followed code?

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"  //I don't know ignore what for the code in pic.
#include "subfolder/ClassTwo.h"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

but ignore what?

I tried one answer but pop one error:
for

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
```

it  pop:

```
warning: expected [error|warning|ignored] after â#pragma GCC diagnosticâ
```

Comment: Is that an out of order constructor initialization list in Boost?

Comment: yes, so I don't know what waning's name I should write in pragma.

Answer (score 2):

It is strange to see this warning popping up in Boost.  The compiler flag to disable this warning is `-Wno-reorder`, as per [gcc's man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc).

In your case, you can use:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wreorder"
```

Comment: many thanks to you, but how you know the flag is -Wno-reorder

Comment: I ran into a similar situation recently, so it was fresh on my mind.  I've included a reference in my answer to the man page for gcc, which includes a list of all warning flags including the "reorder" flag which covers your situation.  Most of those flags also work in VS.

Comment: ./Engine.h:21: warning: expected [error|warning|ignored] after â#pragma GCC diagnosticâ
./Engine.h:22: warning: unknown option after â#pragma GCC diagnosticâ kind

Comment: #pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wno-reorder"
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

Comment: I am not a VS expert, but try removing the "no-" from the front: `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wreorder"`

Comment: yes ,it is ignored "-Wreorder". it can work, but the push/pop can't work